# iTextSharp parse table

Tags: pdf, itext

Using iTextSharp v5.5.13

I have a huge amount of PDF files I need to parse. About 5% of them have a table with data I also need.

The table looks like this:
[image]

Most of the time the line I need is parsed as
`2 januari 15 januari € 49,49 € 21,57 € 15,09 € 34,39`

I can work with that. I split by space and it works.
But sometimes the month name has an extra space: `janu ari`

I know I can override the strategies to get rid of these extra spaces. I'm already using it with the rest of the pdf (`ITextExtractionStrategy`), but for this table, I'm using a rectangle strategy:

```
var rect = new System.util.RectangleJ(70, 425, 460, 200);
RenderFilter[] filter = { new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect) };
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy =
    new FilteredTextRenderListener(new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
var lines = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNumber, strategy).Split('\n');
```

My override looks like this:

```
public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    protected override bool IsChunkAtWordBoundary(TextChunk chunk, TextChunk previousChunk)
    {
        var dist = chunk.DistanceFromEndOf(previousChunk);
        return dist < -chunk.CharSpaceWidth || dist > chunk.CharSpaceWidth / 2.0f;
    }
}
```

I found this Googling. But it doesn't solve my problem.
In the case of `janu ari` `dist` is larger than `-chunk.CharSpaceWidth` and I'm not sure what to do next.

Please let me know when I should not use a rectangle strategy for this table but a different approach.

Comment: How about a brute force approach? Do you expect your data in this type of table always to be in this format? Are there always names of months? Those are predictable. Let's try to think outside of the box. How about you drop all spaces, then your string becomes `2januari15januari€49,49€21,57€15,09€34,39`. That's not too hard to parse with a regular expression. `([0-9]){1,2}(a-z)*([0-9]){1,2}(a-z)*(€[0-9]{1-},[0-9]{2})(€[0-9]{1-},[0-9]{2})(€[0-9]{1-},[0-9]{2})`. I did not test this regex, and I'm sure it could be refined further.

Comment: Thanks @AmedeeVanGasse for suggesting the brute force approach. That seems to work for me using this RegEx: `new Regex(@"([0-9]{1,2})([a-z]*)([0-9]{1,2})([a-z]*)(€[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{2})(€[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{2})(€[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{2})(€[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{2})")`

Comment: In theory you could capture the months with `(januari|februari|maart|april|mei|juni|juli|augustus|september|oktober|november|december)` but yeah whatever, that is just premature optimization and `([a-z]*)` will do the job just as well.

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data in this type of table is always going to be in the same format, then you could take a different approach: just accept whatever data your `MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy` is throwing at you, and then massage that data into a format that you can use.

In this case, you data is always:

- 2 groups of:

  - 1 or 2 digits (day of the month)
  - some characters (name of the month)
- 4 groups of:

  - Euro symbol
  - some digits (at least one)
  - comma
  - 2 digits

In `2 januari 15 januari € 49,49 € 21,57 € 15,09 € 34,39` the spaces are separation characters, but with such well structured data, you don't even need spaces. So just drop them, and then your data becomes `2januari15januari€49,49€21,57€15,09€34,39`.

Now you can use a regular expression with some capture groups, to massage your data into something palatable.

- 2 groups of:

  - `[0-9]{1,2}`
  - `[a-z]*`
- 4 groups of:

  - `€`
  - `[0-9]{1,}`
  - `,`
  - `[0-9]{2}`

As you wrote yourself in the comments, one possible resulting regular expression could be:

```
new Regex(@"([0-9]{1,2})([a-z]*)([0-9]{1,2})([a-z]*)(€[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{2})(€[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{2})(€[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{2})(€[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{2})")
```

Comment: I've marked your answer as the solution. It works even better than expected because I also get some lines with 4 digits for a year, now and then. I've made changes to the RegEx and now these lines are parsed correctly as well.

Comment: And there was great rejoicing!